# Tomcat8 as a Windows service - listen on network socket

Tags: windows, tomcat, service, netstat

Are there difference in the way how Tomcat8 is bind to windows network socket whe is started from console (by startup.bat) of if is started as a windows service? I am not able to connect to application web if Tomcat is started as a windows service. See netstat if started from console:

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC10\bin>netstat -abnop tcp | grep -i -B2 8089
>     [java.exe]**
>
> TCP    0.0.0.0:8089           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6016

See netstat if started as a service (notice different name of listening process):

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC10\bin>netstat -abnop tcp | grep -i -B2 8089
>     [tomcat8.exe]**
>
> TCP    0.0.0.0:8089           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2856

Windows service was created by documentation: '**service.bat** Install'. 
"Image path" of service is: "c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC10\bin\tomcat8.exe" //RS//Tomcat8

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing you should do:
Check your Windows Firewall :)

When you say "different name of listening process", are you talking about the PID? Have you tried to use "ProcessExplorer" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to check the discrepancies between the Java processes that are created when you start the Tomcat instance?

When you mouse over the java process you can see the JVM arguments assigned for that JVM instance, also, when you right-click the java.exe process you can check its properties, on the "TCP/IP" tab you can check if your Tomcat is listening on the right port. Try to start Tomcat using both approaches and take a closer look with ProcessExplorer, that should help you identify any misconfiguration.

Comment: No I am talking really about "process name", some edit my post and reformated commands :-/

Comment: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.0-RC10\bin>netstat -abnop tcp | grep -i -B2 8089
  [java.exe]

  TCP    0.0.0.0:8089           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6016

Comment: Uh, I do not know how to use this UI to correct formatting. My command end with number 8089, the rest  (including 'java' or 'tomcat' string is netstat output.

Comment: Yeah, the process name reflects the windows service name, that should be ok. I understand you are trying to check the discrepancies between the Command-line & Windows Service Tomcat instances because, with the latter, you can't connect to your web application, correct?

Comment: Ok so, assuming that you changed the default port from 8080 to 8089, can you `telnet localhost 8089` ? I would still check both 'java.exe' and 'tomcat8.exe' with ProcessExplorer to investigate. Also, did you check your Windows Firewall?

Comment: Solved, there was not exception in the Firewall for Tomcat8.exe process but only for java.exe. This cause such strange behaviour. 
I cant realize there is such big difference between running process from console and as a windows service :-/ Also if started as from cmdline, it consume about 140MB of RAM comapare to 190MB if started as service

Thanks theMarceloR for contribution.

Comment: No worries @user2956477, would you mind accepting/upvoting the answer? :) Again, about the memory allocation, I would check the tomcat8.exe in ProcessExplorer, it will show you all the JVM arguments as soon as you mouse over, check if you have the same args, you might find some discrepancies.